# Использование Regex в PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Почему выражение <\s*html[^>]*>(.*?) работает на сайте https://regex101.com/ но в коде на php выводит пустой массив?

```
<?php
preg_match_all(
  '/<\s*html[^>]*>(.*?)/' ,
  '<!DOCTYPE html> <html class="no-js" lang="en"><head>',
$matches
);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: А на regex101 использовал модификатор `U`? `'/<\s*html[^>]*>(.*?)/U'`?

Comment: нет, вопрос уже решен благодаря @Dima Kaukin Массив был не пустой, просто я не видел результата поскольку не смотрел html код

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем верно все делаешь верно только это html страница и вывод html тэгов не будет, если бы был пустой тэг `<p></p>`, тыбы то же ничего не увидел.

Если это хром зайди в sources и увидешь там что массив не пустой (`ctrl + shift + i`)